# Jquery validation is applying when typing or focus out

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have my login form in my project and I 
have used Jquery validation js for validating 
user inputs from the example given in net . It is 
Working fine it the problem is that the validation
 started working even when I am starting typing and
focus out of text boxes , I only want the validation 
in the time of form submit. Is there any option available

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#myform").validate({
  onfocusout: false
});
```